# How to specify 'main' for bower package that doesn't have one defined? (Grunt workflow)

Tags: gruntjs, bower, bower-install

Most bower packages have their main file defined in their own bower.json. Example:

```
"main": "masonry.js"
```

Using this main declaration, the bowerInstall grunt task knows to add the package to the build block like so:

```
    <!-- build:js scripts/plugins.js -->
    <script src="bower_components/masonry/scripts/masonry.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

So the problem is that, for whatever reason, some packages don't specify a 'main' and consequently the grunt task doesn't add anything to the build block.

What would be the proper way to set the main for a package in this situation?

I know it isn't to:

- Edit the bower.json of the package itself since that will get git
  ignored.
- Adding the dependency script tag manually outside the build
  block feels pretty sloppy...

Is there any 'right' way to specify the main of a bower package that doesn't specify one?

Comment: are you using grunt-wiredep ? without it, standard behavior is "Adding the dependency script tag manually INside the build block "

Comment: I'm using grunt-bower-install. I suspect wiredep would have the same problem when there is no main defined though?

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer, you can specify by using overiddes in your main bower.json file. Example:

```js
  "overrides":{
    "owlcarousel":{
      "main": "owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"
    }
  }
```